# ROS Nodes and topics - are nodes really decoupled?

Tags: nodes, ros, decoupling

> Note how the two sides are decoupled. All the hokuyo_node node does is
>   publish scans, without knowledge of whether anyone is subscribed. All
>   the rviz does is subscribe to scans, without knowledge of whether
>   anyone is publishing them. The two nodes can be started, killed, and
>   restarted, in any order, without inducing any error conditions.

We all know these statements that using topics, decouples ROS nodes. However reading the documentation on how the connection between the nodes established makes me question this statement. However in the transport section states the following:

> Given a publisher URI, a subscribing node negotiates a connection,
>   using the appropriate transport, with that publisher, via XMLRPC. The
>   result of the negotiation is that the two nodes are connected, with
>   messages streaming from publisher to subscriber.
>
> Each transport has its own protocol for how the message data is
>   exchanged. For example, using TCP, the negotiation would involve the
>   publisher giving the subscriber the IP address and port on which to
>   call connect. **The subscriber then creates a TCP/IP socket to the
>   specified address and port.** The nodes exchange a Connection Header
>   that includes information like the MD5 sum of the message type and the
>   name of the topic, and then the publisher begins sending serialized
>   message data directly over the socket.

So my question is, are the publisher and the subscriber really decoupled? After all in order the subscriber to get a message it has to open TSP/IP connection the the publisher port. And if the publishers are n the subscriber needs to open n connections. This means that it's not completely true that the subscriber won't be bothered if one of the publishers fails. So what exactly is meant by that statement that the nodes are decoupled?

Reference:
http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Technical%20Overview

**Answer**:

I also asked this question on the ROS forum and I got pretty decent answer from there [link](http://answers.ros.org/question/203129/ros-nodes-and-topics-are-nodes-really-decoupled/).